# Is it possible to run Hadoop in Pseudo-Distributed operation without HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, local-storage, hdfs

I'm exploring the options for running a hadoop application on a local system.

As with many applications the first few releases should be able to run on a single node, as long as we can use all the available CPU cores (Yes, this is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406839/running-a-standalone-hadoop-application-on-multiple-cpu-cores)). The current limitation is that on our production systems we have Java 1.5 and as such we are bound to Hadoop 0.18.3 as the latest release (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990595/0-20-2-api-hadoop-version-with-java-5)). So unfortunately we can't use [this new feature](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-1367) yet.

The first option is to simply run hadoop in pseudo distributed mode. Essentially: create a complete hadoop cluster with everything on it running on exactly 1 node.

The "downside" of this form is that it also uses a full fledged HDFS. This means that in order to process the input data this must first be "uploaded" onto the DFS ... which is locally stored. So this takes additional transfer time of both the input and output data and uses additional disk space. I would like to avoid both of these while we stay on a single node configuration.

So I was thinking: Is it possible to override the "fs.hdfs.impl" setting and change it from "org.apache.hadoop.dfs.DistributedFileSystem" into (for example) "org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem"?

If this works the "local" hadoop cluster (which can ONLY consist of ONE node) can use existing files without any additional storage requirements and it can start quicker because there is no need to upload the files. I would expect to still have a job and task tracker and perhaps also a namenode to control the whole thing.

Has anyone tried this before?
Can it work or is this idea much too far off the intended use?

Or is there a better way of getting the same effect: Pseudo-Distributed operation without HDFS?

Thanks for your insights.

---

EDIT 2:

This is the config I created for hadoop 0.18.3
conf/hadoop-site.xml using the answer provided by bajafresh4life.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>file:///</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:33301</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker.http.address</name>
    <value>localhost:33302</value>
    <description>
    The job tracker http server address and port the server will listen on.
    If the port is 0 then the server will start on a free port.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>mapred.task.tracker.http.address</name>
    <value>localhost:33303</value>
    <description>
    The task tracker http server address and port.
    If the port is 0 then the server will start on a free port.
    </description>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, although I'm using 0.19.2.  I'm not too familiar with 0.18.3, but I'm pretty sure it shouldn't make a difference.

Just make sure that `fs.default.name` is set to the default (which is `file:///`), and `mapred.job.tracker` is set to point to where your jobtracker is hosted.  Then start up your daemons using bin/start-mapred.sh .  You don't need to start up the namenode or datanodes.  At this point you should be able to run your map/reduce jobs using `bin/hadoop jar ...`

We've used this configuration to run Hadoop over a small cluster of machines using a Netapp appliance mounted over NFS.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That works great. I'll post my config after I've done some further testing.