# Amazon EMR: configuration of running on local file system

Tags: hadoop, emr, amazon-emr

I am currently trying to run a EMR job on local file system. For EMR, the local file system is on the EC2 instance the EMR job created. I followed this link: [Is it possible to run Hadoop in Pseudo-Distributed operation without HDFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546025/is-it-possible-to-run-hadoop-in-pseudo-distributed-operation-without-hdfs)

The configuration seems quite simple, set `fs.default.name` in core-site.xml to `file:///`. Then Hadoop will run on local file system instead of HDFS.

(I've first tried out this configuration with Hadoop on my local machine (Redhat). When set `fs.default.name` to `file:///` doesn't work, but `file://home/<username>/` makes hadoop run smoothly.)

I change this value by adding bootstrap action when creating the jobflow.

```
./elastic-mapreduce --create --alive --subnet <subnet-id> --instance-type c3.2xlarge --bootstrap-action s3://elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/configure-hadoop --args "-c,fs.default.name=file:///"
```

following this EMR document: [Create Bootstrap Actions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html)

The bootstrap action always succeeds, the logs say that it always successfully change this value in core-site.xml.

But hadoop always fail to launch after this bootstrap action giving me this error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Does not contain a valid host:port authority: file:///

I've also tried `fs.default.name=file://home/hadoop/`:
java.net.UnknownHostException: Invalid hostname for server: home

Or, `fs.default.name=file:///home/hadoop/`:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Or, `fs.default.name=file://127.0.0.1/home/hadoop/`:
The namenode log file doesn't even give out a error message. It doesn't have SHUT_DOWN message as other errors. It just suddenly terminates.

Does EMR hadoop work on local file system at all? How do you configure it to do so?

Answer (score 1):

I think the key point here is that running Hadoop on a local file system works fine on a single-node cluster and **EMR is a fully distributed Hadoop cluster**. Take a look at [this](http://blog.pivotal.io/pivotal/products/usage-and-quirks-of-fs-default-name-in-hadoop-filesystem) post about fs.default.name and its usage.